# how to add angular2-bootstrap-confirm to angular2?

Tags: angular

i am new to angular-2, i am trying to add angular2-bootstrap-confirm but showing cannot get errors in the console. i had followed the following docs [click here](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular2-bootstrap-confirm#installation)  is there a another way to do this. can any one help me over this issue.

this is what i am trying to get.is there a another way to get this effect.

[image: this is how i need]

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ConfirmOptions, Position} from 'angular2-bootstrap-confirm';
import {Positioning} from 'angular2-bootstrap-confirm/position/position';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button
      class="btn btn-default"
      mwlConfirm
      [title]="title"
      [message]="message"
      placement="left"
      (confirm)="confirmClicked = true"
      (cancel)="cancelClicked = true"
      [(isOpen)]="isOpen">
      Click me!
    </button>

`,
providers: [ 
    ConfirmOptions,
    {provide: Position, useClass: Positioning}
  ]
})
export class AppComponent { 
public title: string = 'Popover title';
  public message: string = 'Popover description';
  public confirmClicked: boolean = false;
  public cancelClicked: boolean = false;
  public isOpen: boolean = false;
}
```

### app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {ConfirmModule} from 'angular2-bootstrap-confirm';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,ConfirmModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### systemjs.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the modal window is hidden. Try to change `placement` property like:

```
placement="right"
```

And don't forget to add bootstrap css

**Update:**

Change your **systemjs.config.js**:

```
map: {
  app: 'app',
  ....
  'angular2-bootstrap-confirm': 'npm:angular2-bootstrap-confirm'
},
packages: {
  ...
  'angular2-bootstrap-confirm': {
     main: 'angular2-bootstrap-confirm.js',
     defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNj6Pz0g8jhputAZjsNq?p=preview)**

Comment: actually i am getting these errors.localhost/:26 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-bootstrap-confirm(…)

Comment: Could you share your system.js config?

Comment: i am also running angular-2 using gulp where should i place this content(systemjs.config.js:) in gulp file.if you want my gulp i will update.

Comment: Also i am confused when to use gulp at the development phase or production phase. currently i am running angular-2 app(2.0.0-beta.2) with gulp command at the console.please clarify me.